# Postgresql: Query from same table

Tags: postgresql

I have one table:

```
id1  |  date     |  idreff |
A11  | 2015-01-01| A11
B12  | 2016-02-03| A11
C53  | 2016-05-26| A11
```

ID1 have one IDreff. I want to extract two kind of ages from date:
1. Age of the transaction itself
2. Age of the first transaction, based on IDreff.

So, I want this result:

```
id1  |  date     |  idreff | Age of Transaction | Age IDreff

A11  | 2015-01-01| A11    
B12  | 2016-02-03| A11    
C53  | 2016-05-26| A11
```

How I get the result for both query (age of transaction ID1 and IDreff) at same query?

I tried with this:

```
SELECT *, age(t1.date) AS age1, age(t2.date) FROM table t1, table t2 WHERE t1.idreff=t2.id1
```

But the result are not true because give me double for each row.

Answer (score 0):

You may modify your sql like this:

```
SELECT 
    t1.*, age(t1.date) AS age1, age(t1.date, t2.date) 
FROM 
    table t1, table t2 
WHERE 
    t1.idreff=t2.id1
```

Comment: This query give me the same result as my previous query. There are double result.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I do not get it. Could you show some result example ? @bandungeuy

Answer (score 0):

You should write more precise join:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    age(t1.date) AS age1, 
    age(COALESCE(t2.date,t1.date)) as base_age
FROM 
    table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2 ON (t1.idreff=t2.id1 AND t1.id1<>t2.id1)
WHERE 1 = 1
```